# SQL Query- N Level hierarchy - Return Parent and Last Child Only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a multilevel hierarchy data.
I want to combine everything into two level using sql query.
I want to return First parent and and Last Child of the Data

```
PID     CId     Name
Null    1       Electronics
1       2       Laptop
2       3       Toshiba
1       4       Mobile
4       5       Samsung
```

I need the result like this

```
PID     CId     Name
Null    1       Electronics
1       3       Toshiba
1       5       Samsung
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this [tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) I create my ***first*** recursive CTE just for you.

The trick here is mark the row with null as the `BigBoss` and pass that value on the recursive secttion.

The last `where` have two filter

- `PID IS NULL` to show the father item.
- `OR  NOT EXISTS` to show the items without childrens

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f18897/11)** 
Fiddle show your desire output, but if you unncoment the code you could see the full result to better understand.

```
WITH DirectReports (PID, CId, Name, Level, BigBoss)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.PID, e.CId, e.Name, 0 AS Level, e.CId BigBoss
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS e
    WHERE e.PID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.PID, e.CId, e.Name, Level + 1, d.BigBoss
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS e
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.PID = d.CId
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
-- SELECT d.PID, d.CId, d.Name, d.Level, d.BigBoss
-- FROM DirectReports d
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN PID IS NULL THEN NULL
          ELSE BigBoss
       END PID,
       Cid, Name
FROM DirectReports
WHERE  
    PID IS NULL
OR  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM Table1 t
                 WHERE d.CId = t.PID)
```

Result:

```
|    PID | Cid |        Name |
|--------|-----|-------------|
| (null) |   1 | Electronics |
|      1 |   5 |     Samsung |
|      1 |   3 |     Toshiba |
```

Comment: I update my answer to use a recursive CTE and now return the exact output you want.